# Android - Double Value Error only on Real Device

Tags: android, graph, double, achartengine

Here is a fragment of my app used to show a graph using achartengine:

```
private void addSampleData() {
...
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("####.##");
for(i=0; i<count; i++){
   list[i] = Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(list[i])); 
   mCurrentSeries.add(i, list[i]);
}
...
}
```

When i run my app on the emulator there are no problems (with any device and any api), but when i run the app on my real device i get an error like this: "Inavlid Double: 29,32" and if i see the values stored in list[] they are with "," (29,32 - 34,56 - ...)and not with "." (29.32 - 34.56 - ...) like on the emulator.

Why does this happen? How can I do?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having this problem probably because of the language of your device, just force the separator to be the coma.

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');
twoDForm.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
```

Comment: @Gimmy88 bad idea, the provided answer is an implementation what I have suggested below, should be followed! +1

Answer (score 1):

it is about the decimal formatting characters. 
Set your emulator, windows to be locale hungarian or Romanian, as your device and instead of dots you will have the coma as decimal separator!

There is 2 way to soltve this. One is to force a Locale other is to force a decimal separator only.

I am to lazy to provide full code, I hope it helps the idea and you will get it fast with google.

Comment: Thx for the answer! However the problem is caused by DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("####.##"); , because if i don't use it i get numbers like 29.3245646457 and so on, but it works both on the emulator and on the real device, so maybe there's another way to set the number of decimal in a double value...